# Shehechiyanu on Lulav

Tags: halacha, sukkot, chutz-laaretz, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shehecheyanu

Why is it that we make Shehechiyanu both nights of Sukkos at candle lighting and Kiddush due to Sefeika DeYoma yet we only make Shehechiyanu on the Lulav on the first day?

Answer (score 9):

Because in theory you could have said Shehecheyanu when you prepared (bound) your lulav before Sukkos. So even supposing that the second day of Sukkos was the real Yom Tov (and the previous day was actually erev Sukkos), your Shehecheyanu then would still count as the real thing. (By contrast, with kiddush, you're saying the berachah because of the holiday itself - and conceivably it hadn't yet started the first night.)

([Mishnah Berurah 662:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&pgnum=264), citing posekim)

Comment: +1. But— but— You, of all people, are quoting the _MB_ when the _Baal Hatanya_ offers a different reason? `;-)`

Comment: @msh: קבל את האמת ממי שאמרו, right? Anyway, I'm actually not aware of anyplace where the Alter Rebbe talks about this. Please enlighten me!

Comment: I don't know where, either, but someone told me in his name something like the following (which I may well be getting wrong or missing part of, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer): We treat the '_s'feka d'yoma_' day as _yom tov_ for all _k'dushas hayom_ purposes, so any _shehecheyanu_ related to _k'dushas hayom_ is repeated, but not the _shehecheyanu_ on _lulav_ which is a separate _mitzva_.

Comment: See Bach 651 for two options why to delay Shehechiyanu.