# Does the she’hechiyonu brocho apply in any way to getting married?

Tags: blessing, marriage, shehecheyanu

A man getting married has a new suit to put on, on the day of his wedding. He will make the she’hechiyonu brocho. Should he have the “acquisition” of his wife in mind in addition when he pronounces the blessing?

On the one hand she is much more important than a new suit; on the other hand we do not know that she will agree until he attempts to place the ring on her hand.

Comment: IIRC the Sefardim say a שהחיינו on a new טלית under the Chuppa for this very reason.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Do you have a source please?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I've seen some Ashekenazim do that as well (usually those who haven't been wearing a Tallit from Bar Mitzva age)

Answer (score 2):

[Taamei Minhagim #973](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=424) quotes the [Chupat Chatanim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37297&pgnum=59) (and points you to Likutim Chapter 106) that one does not say Shehecheyanu when preforming Kedushin. This is because one says Shehecheyanu when the action of the Mitzvah completes the Mitzvah (i.e. the act one is doing is in itself a complete Mitzvah), e.g. Lulav. But the main Mitzvah of marriage is Reproduction, so Shehecheyanu is not said at the Chupah.

The footnote there quotes a source that says that when one asked HaRav Ohr Shraga Z"L if one should say Shehecheyanu when he gets married, HaRav Shraga responded that a better question would be "should someone say Boruch Dayan HaEmet?"

---

That being said, I'm not sure if your question is asking if one happens to have a new suit by the wedding, thereby necessitating a Shehecheyanu, should he also have in mind the marriage. Or are you saying there is an established custom to make a Shehecheyanu on new clothes by a wedding, and does this Shehecheyanu also go on the marriage.

Comment: I'm not sure which "Likutim" this is, or who HaRav Ohr Shraga is.

Comment: Lulav??? The Shechiyanu there is on preparing the Lulav bundle, not picking it up as the Mitzva

Comment: @DoubleAA: Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 651:5 - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=249

Comment: Not sure what that proves. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21798/759

Comment: @DoubleAA: The Chupat Chatanim (now linked to in the answer) says that this idea is brought in the Abudraham. The Abudraham -- http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=14 says it in the name of the RaMe"H...

Comment: ...On the previous page, the Abudraham explains why we don't make a blessing when we tie the Lulav, but make a blessing when we shake it Based on the Rambam, he makes a distinction between Mitzvot that have a followup Mitzvah afterwards, and those that don't. Tying the Lulav has a followup mitzvah, shaking it, and therefore the blessing is said by shaking, not by tying. Perhaps that is the intention of the Abudraham (however, the Abudraham (pg 13) seems to hold that one should ideally make the Shehecheyanu when tying the Lulav, and only if not make it when shaking).

Comment: The discussion on the previous page about having a follow up part or not is about the main birkat hamitzva (asher kiddeshanu...al netillat lulav) not the Shehechiyanu. Note the Ramah as quoted in Abudarham does not use Lulav as an example; that is the Chuppat Chatanim's addition.

Comment: @DoubleAA: correct, When I started writing the comment I intended to make that more clear. -- Without delving into it too deeply, we may have a disagreement among the Poskim about when to Say the Shehecheyanu on the Lulav. The Abudraham seems to say that one should LeChatchila make the blessing when tying the Lulav, and the Shulchan Aruch seems to say that one should LeChatchila make the blessing when shaking the Lulav (even though one could make it when tying the Lulav - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10704) understanding the root of the disagreement should help us understand our case.

Comment: I don't think it will help. The Rosh (4:2) says the Minhag nowadays is to delay the Shehechiyanu till the time of the Mitzva, but seemingly not for any fundamental reason. The reason given in the Mordechai (769) is equally if not even more technical.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9397/discussion-between-menachem-and-double-aa)