# Shehechianu at a wedding?

Tags: blessing, wedding, shehecheyanu

The Rosh and the Rambam argue about whether Kiddushin is a mitzvah in its own right or if it's a preparation for the various mitzvos that can only be done when married, such as having children. The Rosh (Kesubos 1:12) holds of the latter view; the Rambam (Ishus 1:1-2) holds of the former view.

Generally speaking, Ashkenazim follow the Rosh, who himself was Ashkenazi, while the Sefardim follow the Rambam, who was also Sefardi. (This is a bit of an oversimplification, but that's the general idea: Ashkenazim follow Ashkenazi poskim, and likewise for Sefardim.) Thus, it's understandable why Ashkenazim don't make a Shehechiyanu under the chuppah, as we hold that it's not a mitzvah in its own right. But why do Sefardim only make a brachah because of the Tallis (see [this article](http://www.aish.com/jl/l/m/48969841.html), at the end of the "Chuppah" section)? If they hold like the Rambam, they should be able to make a Shehechiyanu without having a Tallis!

Comment: Why should they make a Shehechiyanu just because it's a Mitzva?

Comment: @DoubleAA Isn't that what a Shehechiyanu is - the first time one is performing a mitzvah or doing something new? A hechsher I can understand; it's not an action in and of itself and therefore doesn't warrant a Shehechiyanu. But the actual act of a mitzvah should deserve one, the same way one makes a Shehechiyanu on shofar, lulav, Sukkah, and Yom Tov on the first day it's done.

Comment: @DonielF Well Rambam is also particularly strict with berakha l'vatalah, and safek berakhot l'hakel...

Comment: of interest: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29573/603

Comment: See [here](https://www.toraland.org.il/מאמרים/חברה-ומשפחה/נישואים/ברכת-שהחיינו-בשעת-הנישואין/) a a lot of sources

Comment: @DonielF This year wasn't the first time I heard shofar but we said shehchiyanu. You seem quite unsure of the parameters involved.

Comment: @DoubleAA And likewise for first fruits - we often have the same fruits we had last RH, but since we haven't had them in the past year we make a Shehechiyanu. Why should shofar or yom tov or any of the other examples I gave be any different? By extension, were Kiddushin to be on the list it, too, would necessitate a Shehechiyanu each time, were one not to get divorced and remarried within the year.

Comment: @DonielF The length of a "year" has nothing to do with anything. You seem quite unsure of the parameters involved. If I happen to not Shecht a cow for a year, then I say Shehechiyanu on doing so? No. Put up a Mezuza for the first time in a year? No. Eat a carrot for the first time in a year? No. Separate Terumah? No.

Comment: A lot here https://www.jewishideas.org/article/sheheheyanu-blessing , also maybe one can say it not for the Mitzvah just for the happiness in aquiering a (this) wife  (that some grooms may have)